# Custom button with VF page taking long time to update records

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-button

I was working on one custom action on detail page, on click the button will update the same record and also its parent record.

I created an apex class and VF page to do the same but on clicking button, its taking time to update the record, can anyone help me out in this issue here.

My VF page and class are working fine but they are taking time to update.

VF Page:

```
  <apex:page standardController="Lease_2__c" extensions="DeviationButton" action="{!MyActionMethod}" lightningStylesheets="true">
  <apex:outputPanel id="MESSAGES">
       <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
  </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:page>
```

Apex class:

```
public class DeviationButton {
public Lease_2__c lease{get;set;}
public Opportunity opp{get;set;}
public DeviationButton(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    lease = new Lease_2__c();
    lease = [select Id, Opportunity__c,Stage__c from Lease_2__c Where Id=: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')];
    
        
    opp = new Opportunity();
    opp = [select Id, StageName from Opportunity where Id =: lease.Opportunity__c];
    
}
public void MyActionMethod()
{
    lease.Stage__c='Legal Review';
    opp.StageName = 'Deal Approved';
    update lease;
    update opp;
    //PageReference pg;
    //pg=new PageReference('/' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'));
    //pg.getParameters().put('message','Saved Successfully');
    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Lease Has Been Successfully Recalled. Thank You!'));
    //pg.setRedirect(true);
}

}
```

Comment: welcome to SFSE; please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community.  Your question is going to get closed without some work on your part to demonstrate research. I'd suggest starting with this [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/developer_console/developer_console_logs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few thoughts:

1. You are using an extension, but you are querying your record. Put all the fields you may need on your VF page with rendered="false" and use the standard getRecord() method.
2. Do your Opportunity query in your update method so the page loads faster.
3. Move the Opportunity query and update to a @future method so you can redirect the user and let the dml happen in the background. You won't get any errors shown, but you can show the confirmation message. It will make the user experience better. If you can guarantee that you won't hit any Opportunity errors, then this may be the best way to execute that second query and dml.